# undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1' for C-only code

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

I am building a bare-metal code for ARM926 and I need the generated output to be as tight as possible.

In my best effort, though, I still receive this error:

```
yocto/poky/build-idprint/tmp/work/idprint-poky-linux-gnueabi/idpr/1.0-r0/
recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a(raise.o):
(.ARM.exidx+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
```

In my `Makefile` I put this linker flags:

```
LD_OPT    = -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-build-id=none -flto
LD_LINK   = -static -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--start-group,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group
LDFLAGS   = -T $(BINARY).ld -Xlinker -Map=$(BINARY).map $(LD_OPT)
```

And the link command is

```
$(LINK.cc) $(OBJS) $(LD_LINK) src/lib_dummies.o -o $(BINARY).elf
```

Finally I have a custom linker script as simple as possible:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(fiq_main)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x0;
  .text : {
    KEEP(*(.textEntry));
    *(.text*)
    *(.text .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
  }
  . = ALIGN(1024);
  _bss_start = .;
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss : { *(.bss) }
  _bss_end = .;
}
```

I added a custom dummy `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1` to my code (inspired from libgcc sources) but it didn't help.

I have read about quite a few pages around the web but none explained me why is `libgcc` trying to link a `C++` function to my `C`-only project.
Okay, `$(LINK.cc)` is evaluated to `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++` but I still se no sense trying to link a `C++` function to `libgcc`. It would make sense if I was linking `libstdc++`. Moreover, $(LD) fails for othre reasons (can't find `-lgcc`).

No optimization flags I could find helped me with this either.

Look, it is very important that my code doesn't add any uneeded stuff.
Everything started only because I need to use integer division (unresolved `__aeabi_idiv`...)

---

I omitted the optimization flags for simplicity but, if needed, please tell me and I'll add them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

after a very long battle, I ended with a relatively simple solution.
In my Makefile, I changed the `LD_LINK` line to:

```
LD_LINK   = -static -nostartfiles -nostdlib -lgcc
```

(removed `-Wl,--start-group,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group`)

This led me to an `undefined reference to raise`.
Then I added this few lines to an assembly source file:

```
    .global raise

raise:
    b raise
```

**Note:**

I tried creating a `raise` function in C but, due to name mangling and despite any tricks I've tried, the linker could never find it.

I'd be really happy if someone could show me how to do that in plain C.

**Bonus:**

My final binary is **way** smaller than what I was getting before, and it is just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found this issue only exists on arm32 but not aarch64. And it happens even when built with pure C code (so apparently no C++ exceptions). The linker complains about missing __aeabi_unwind_cpp_prX, but actually, they are never invoked by disassembling the binaries. Probably there's a bug in the linker? Anyway, the solution is to define their stub symbols and they will be orphan symbols in the final binary.

By the way, adding `-fno-exceptions` option to the compiler doesn't help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

These issues usually arise when building for bare-metal targets (hence `-nostdlib`) with toolchains meant for GNU/Linux targets (e.g `arm-none-linux-gnueabihf`) instead of using the bare-metal toolchains (e.g `arm-none-eabi`).
Always use the appropriate toolchain from [here](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads).

One problem you'd avoid are unresolved references to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_prX`, which cannot be [silenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77078541/8925535) with `-fno-exceptions`. The `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_prX` routines are defined in `libgcc.a` in the bare-metal toolchain whereas in the Linux toolchain, they live in `libgcc_eh.a`. So just linking with `-nostdlib -lgcc` is enough.

Another thing is the libc `raise` function, which the bare metal compiler would not emit references to.